# Parent Directory File Path in Javascript not working in Linux

Tags: javascript, linux

I built a website and have been testing it on a Mac with no problems for several weeks. I am now working in ubuntu. I copied my webiste with all the folders and files to the desktop of my Linux machine. It stopped working. I narrowed it down to a file path problem.

I'll give a simplified version of the problem with one html file and two js files (plus jquery).

In the index.html file I have:

```
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="first.js"></script>
```

In first.js I have:

```
$("body").append("<script src=second.js></script>");
```

In second.js I have:

```
$("body").append("hello");
```

This works fine when I keep all the files in the same directory/folder.

It also works if I put second.js inside a directory "child" and change first.js like this:

```
$("body").append("<script src=child/second.js></script>");
```

However, if I put second.js in the parent directory and change first.js to:

```
$("body").append("<script src=../second.js></script>");
```

all of a sudden it stops working.

I read up on linux file path systems, but mostly I get explanations of how the command line works and it doesn't help me. I don't understand how to fix the problem and more importantly I am concerned that even if I change the file path to work on my Linux desktop it will then stop working once I upload it back on an actual server. I am really enjoying working inside the Linux environment and would like to continue testing my website in it, but I don't know what is going on with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a security issue on your folder. By default the folder is not inheriting parent permissions. Check your Linux folder permissions for the web_user who is accessing the folder.